# Dynamically adjusting widget's content and layout to the size the user defined through resize. Android

Tags: android, android-widget

Android design pattern guide says widget's content and layout can be dynamically adjusted to the size the user defined through resize operation here: [Design guide for widgets](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html)

Example provided in the design guide:
[image: Example image provided in the design guide.]

But I do not see anything in the docs as to how to accomplish this. How do we change the layout as per resize operation? Any ideas regarding the approach will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that this is a Jellybean+ feature, because of the `AppWidgetProvider#onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` method. [One](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/android-homescreen-widget-with-alarmmanager/) example I found implementing it.

Comment: Is there a way to know the dimensions of the widget so that we can render an appropriate view? Jellybean+ is also fine.

Comment: @A--C Thank you for your directions. I'm able to proceed as I wrote in the answer below for JB devices. Please write an answer so that I can award you the bounty.

Comment: You could wait until the bounty expires and answer your own question. All I did was link you to an example :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thanks to A--C , this is possible for Jellybean and above devices and is simple to implement.
Below is the sample code using `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged` method

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context,
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Changed dimensions");

    // See the dimensions and
    Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId);

    // Get min width and height.
    int minWidth = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int minHeight = options
            .getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);

            // Obtain appropriate widget and update it.
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,
            getRemoteViews(context, minWidth, minHeight));

    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId,
            newOptions);
}

/**
 * Determine appropriate view based on width provided.
 * 
 * @param minWidth
 * @param minHeight
 * @return
 */
private RemoteViews getRemoteViews(Context context, int minWidth,
        int minHeight) {
    // First find out rows and columns based on width provided.
    int rows = getCellsForSize(minHeight);
    int columns = getCellsForSize(minWidth);

    if (columns == 4) {
        // Get 4 column widget remote view and return
    } else {
                    // Get appropriate remote view.
        return new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.quick_add_widget_3_1);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns number of cells needed for given size of the widget.
 * 
 * @param size Widget size in dp.
 * @return Size in number of cells.
 */
 private static int getCellsForSize(int size) {
  int n = 2;
  while (70 * n - 30 < size) {
    ++n;
  }
  return n - 1;
 }
```

Comment: Firstly, You should not limit yourself with 4 cells only. Use a loop like this: http://pastebin.com/reexPt1m . Secondly, you forget to acount screen density. Thirdly, there is no guarantee, that widget sized 264dp will take up 4 cells. One of my Sony devices fits 264dp into 3 cells. You should work with the layout width in dp and not cells.

Comment: @Pius Updated the code for obtaining cells. Thank you. True should not limit with 4 cells only. While there is no guarantee that it will take up 4 cells, it will be a good estimate to base your layout on.

Comment: Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId); is the same as returned Bundle newOptions

Comment: Better implementation of getCellsForSize() : return (int)(Math.ceil(size + 30d)/70d);

Comment: Why after changing layouts `public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) { //some click events }` is not called anymore?

Comment: @Choletski, do you found any solution?

Comment: @Choletski
I post my solution in answer to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Gogu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14301127/6126110) response and according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15738825/6126110) about how to get widget size, I'm created this `WidgetClass` in `Kotlin`:

```
class WidgetClass: AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {

        for (id in appWidgetIds!!) {
            //get widget options for later get widget dimensions
            val options = appWidgetManager?.getAppWidgetOptions(id)
            //get widget view based on widget size
            val view = getView(context, options)
            //update widget
            appWidgetManager!!.updateAppWidget(id, view)
        }

    }

    //listen for widget changes
    override fun onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?,
                                           appWidgetId: Int, newOptions: Bundle?) {

        //update widget view based on new options
        appWidgetManager?.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, getView(context, newOptions))

        super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions)
    }

    private fun getView(context: Context?, options: Bundle?): RemoteViews {

        val minWidth: Int
        val minHeight: Int

        if (context!!.resources.configuration.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            || context.resources.configuration.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT) {

            minWidth = options?.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH) ?: 0
            minHeight = options?.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT) ?: 0

        } else {

            minWidth = options?.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH) ?: 0
            minHeight = options?.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT) ?: 0

        }

        //get widget view accordin widget size
        return if (minWidth >= 240)
            RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_large)
        else
            RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_small)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Choletski
@azendh

> After changing layouts  some click events are not called anymore

I solved this problem by creating function that setOnClickPendingIntent
on view, and then return it.

For example the code is like

```
private RemoteViews getConfiguredView (RemoteViews remoteViews, Context context){

    Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context, EarningsWidget.class);
    refreshIntent.setAction(REFRESH_ACTION);
    PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 3, refreshIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refreshButton, toastPendingIntent);
    return remoteViews;
}
```

And than function is called where you do *"Get appropriate remote view."*

```
return getConfiguredView(new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_widget), context);
```