# update widget with multiple layouts

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an app that need to change different layouts for widget, depending on size, for exemple if widget is 4x2 cells then set up widget_layout, esle set up widget_layout1.

For this change I use @Gogu's [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14301127/3595288):

```
    @Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {

    Log.d("widget", "Changed dimensions");

    // See the dimensions and
    Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId);

    // Get min width and height.
    int minWidth = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int minHeight = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);

    // Obtain appropriate widget and update it.
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, getRemoteViews(context, minWidth, minHeight));

    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
}

/**
 * Determine appropriate view based on width provided.
 *
 * @param minWidth
 * @param minHeight
 * @return
 */
private RemoteViews getRemoteViews(Context context, int minWidth, int minHeight) {

    // First find out rows and columns based on width provided.
    int rows = getCellsForSize(minHeight);
    int columns = getCellsForSize(minWidth);

    Log.d("dinazaur coloane", "nr este: " + columns);
    Log.d("dinazaur randuri", "nr este: " + rows);


    if (columns == 4) {
        // Get 4 column widget remote view and return
        return new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.simple_widget);
    } else {
        // Get appropriate remote view.
        return new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.simple_widget2);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns number of cells needed for given size of the widget.
 *
 * @param size Widget size in dp.
 * @return Size in number of cells.
 */
private static int getCellsForSize(int size) {
    return (int) (Math.ceil(size + 30d) / 70d);
}
```

I can't understand why after changing widget layout size( get it bigger -> change to layout_simple1 and then smaller changing to layout_simple back ), `onUpdate()` method that handle onClick PendingIntent for layout_simple is not working any more (is not even called), the code is:

```
  @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        String number = String.format("%03d", (new Random().nextInt(900) + 100));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, number);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);


    }
}
```

my widget xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/simple_widget"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard">

</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign your OnClickPendingIntent before updateAppWidget invocation. Pay attention on description **public void partiallyUpdateAppWidget (int appWidgetId, RemoteViews views)** that *"Note that because these updates are not cached, any state that they modify that is not restored by restoreInstanceState will not persist in the case that the widgets are restored using the cached version in AppWidgetService."*

E.g. if you change something (not all) on your widget via RemoteView, invoke updateAppWidget and rotate a screen, then Widget will restore only the data was added to the widget before updateAppWidget invocation. All other data will be lost.