# Getting the Dimensions of a Home Screen Widget's Element

Tags: android, widget, homescreen, home-screen-widget

I am working on a widget, where I need to have a chart displayed in addition to some text fields. I have figured out how to generate a visualization of the graph and then convert it to a bitmap, which gets placed in the `ImageView`. The problem is the following:

In a normal Android app, I would get the width and height of the `ImageView` and pass these as parameters for the bitmap generation. This way, the image will be fitting perfectly within its container. Since I am using a home screen widget, this is not possible, as far as I am aware, though. As a result of this, I am trying to derive the size of the `ImageView` by trying to figure out what size would the text fields have, but I also have to calculate those and so far have had no luck with getting it right. What I end up with is always having excess space above and beneath the image, or on its sides and the size of this is really varying according to the screen the widget is presented on. You can see some examples in the two links below.

[Example A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYIzm.jpg) *This is the default widget size. For this screen, only a small gap can be seen on the sides of the graph.*

[Example B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N00f.jpg) *Resizing the widget and recalculating the size leads to having bigger gaps on the two sides, though. For other screens the issue can be even more jarring.*

My question is:
**How could I get/calculate the necessary resolution for my bitmap?**

Comment: Override `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` -- you can get a range of possible sizes via that callback. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#AppWidgetProvider. However, there is no means to get a precise dimension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the size of my homescreen widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153604/get-the-size-of-my-homescreen-widget)