# Is it possible to obtain provided area for widgets by phone without widgetId in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, glance-appwidget, glance, home-screen-widget

I am new to Glance library and want to learn provided are for widgets from phone before I place the widget in the home screen. Currently, when I put the widget home screen  I check the provided area like this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501760/14221638) it is working without any problem however this is not what I want. My widgets are 2x2 is there any solution that I can learn it without giving widgetId?